# OSX - freeing space

Tags: macos, disk-space

I'm trying to free some space on my mac. What's the 'Other' entry below in my screenshot? There's a separate entry for 'System' and 'Applications'.

Also, when I did:

```
du -h Documents
```

in my /Users/wasteland, it reported only 6.5GB (not 133GB as in the screenshot). I'm the only user on this system and only use this particluar user account. Where's the other over 100GB of documents?!

[image: Storage Utilisation]

Comment: You need to use programs that're more specific about the locations using a lot of space. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264043/macos-sierra-cannot-find-what-is-using-all-disk-space) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk) for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. I've had much more luck with ncdu